# Convergence of random variables, convergence in probability/a.s./$L^p$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I just started this new section of probability and I'm not so sure on how to resolve these statements:

> Let $(X_n)_{n≥1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1−\frac1{n^2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=n^3)=\frac1{n^2}$

> a) Show that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability

My attempt: The sequence converges in probability to $0$ if $\forall\epsilon>0 \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}[\left|X_n-0\right|>\epsilon]=0$. Here I have $\mathbb{P}[\left|X_n-0\right|>\epsilon]=\mathbb{P}[\left|X_n\right|>\epsilon]=\mathbb{P}[X_n>\epsilon]=\frac1{n^2}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

> b) Show that it is not true that $X_n \rightarrow0$ in $L^p$ for $p≥1$.

Attempt: The sequence converges in $L^p$ to $0$ if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[\left|X_n-0\right|^p]=0$. Well really I don't know how to proceed to show that $\mathbb{E}[\left|X_n\right|^p]\not=0$ since the PDF of $X_n$ is unknown.

> c) Show that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ a.s.

Attempt: The sequence converges a.s. to $0$ when $\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in\Omega :0=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n(\omega)\}]=1$. But here I get $\mathbb{P}(X_\infty=0)=1 $ and $\mathbb{P}(X_\infty=\infty)=0$, but since the last one doesn't make sense, we get the result.(??)

Any suggestion/hint/correction is appreciated.

Comment: You say 'the PDF of $X_n$ is unknown' but that's exactly what you're given in the statement of the question: $X_n(x)=(1-\frac1{n^2})\delta(x-0)+\frac1{n^2}\delta(x-n^3)$ (with some slight abuse of notation). The cumulative is 0 for $x\lt 0$, $1-\frac1{n^2}$ for $0\lt x\lt n^3$, and 1 for $x\gt n^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to (a) looks OK. For (b), notice that you can compute the expectation by: $$E(|X_n|^p) = 0^p P(X_n = 0)+n^{3p}P(X_n=n^3) = n^{3p-2}$$
Now let $n \to \infty$ and conclude.

As a hint for (c): what does the Borel-Cantelli lemma tell us about $P(X_n > 0\, \text{ infinitely often})$?